# How to group properly excel data source with rowspan?

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, datasource, grouping

From my understanding, `<groupExpression>` tag will be the one that decides whether a new group will be created or not, if there's a change to the element inside `<groupExpression>`, a new group will be created.

I want my report to look similar to my Excel data source (refer below) hence I want to group the `ID` and `Name` in the Excel file. In my jasperReport.jrxml (refer below), my `<groupExpression>` for `Group1` is the `ID` column of my Excel File. But when I preview the report (refer below), the `ID` and `Name` column is not grouped, instead, there's a `null` string.

How to properly group them and eliminate the `null` string?

**Excel datasource:**

[image: Excel datasource]

**jasperReport.jrxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
<!-- 2016-01-26T15:33:41 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="FirstJasperReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8b8832df-588e-4202-826e-a6b3efcbd22b">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="ExcelDataBase"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Title" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Balance" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="Balance1" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Group1" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Balance}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="Balance2" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Group1" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Balance}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="30">
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="400" height="30" backcolor="#DEFCF2" uuid="de6c2f8d-afa6-45b4-b40e-574f2e07057e"/>
                </rectangle>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="c028645d-9b29-42d3-b91e-d47f15a5b44a"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="85d2844f-ef91-47a1-9223-c6943a25fe4d"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        ......
```

**Preview result:**

[image]

How to make `title1` and `title2` appear under the group `test1`, without the `null` string (similar to the Excel source file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the excel datasource is passing `$F{ID}==null`  for second record. This generates the `null` group (as you can see also the `name` is `null`).

The easiest way to fix it is to **not use rowspan** in excel (include all data in the excel sheet).

If this is not possible you need to save the first `$F{ID}` value and return this if `$F{ID}==null`

**Example**

```xml
<variable name="First_ID" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Group1" calculation="First">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

In group return variable `$V{First_ID}` if `$F{ID}==null`

```xml
<group name="Group1">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}==null?$V{First_ID}:$F{ID}]]></groupExpression>
    ... your groupHeader ....
</group>
```

Comment: What is the meaning of rowspan in Excel? Do you mean merging of cells across the row? Like what I did to A2 and A3?

Comment: Yes exactly, the merging of cells return null for second record